# No GTK includes

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gtk, codeblocks

After Code::Blocks IDE installation on my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, i've created new C++ project with GTK template to play with in it (GNU C++). But if try to build it, i get error:

```
/home/surrp/Project1-gtk/Project1/main.c|2|fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory|
```

As i am new to linux, i don't know where Code::Blocks looks for GTK headers and how to install them. Is it really such unreliable like in Windows - i have to download headers and put somewhere manually?? Isn't there any package in repos?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup GTK+ to develop with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921460/how-to-setup-gtk-to-develop-with-codeblocks-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Header files are usually in the /usr/include folder.

To build GTK apps, you have to install development files for GTK (in my system, for example, there are `libgtk+2.0-devel` and `libgtk+3.0-devel` packages) Then you should modify compiler and linker settings as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921460/how-to-setup-gtk-to-develop-with-codeblocks-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: creating symlinks instead of actually fixing the build environment to use pkg-config sounds like the wrong thing to do...