# C++ : Mini Project on Cryptography

Tags: c++, graphics, cryptography, project

I need to encrypt and decrypt files using C++ with XOR Encryption. I need to know where I can make a GUI for it.

Is there a way to do this (possibly through C++ alone) ?

Comment: Clearly off topic for this site.

Comment: @RicharCritten Where should I ask then ?

Comment: If you're looking for someone to write software for you, then you should ask a software engineer. If you're trying to write the software then you should learn C++ either through a class and/or from reading instructional C++ books.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm just asking the way to do it. I don't want the code. I just want to know if this all can be done with C++ alone ?

Comment: The simple answer is yes, the long answer is that if you're wanting to create a GUI then you'll need to use other C++ libraries like SDL, OpenGL, ...

Comment: @JohnnyHenly Thanks. That's what I needed to know.

Comment: Note: It is very hard to get cryptography right and by "right" I mean secure. It this is just playing fine but if it is a real project with real users the security needs to be professionally done.

Comment: @Zalph it's just a project which won't be used professionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quite simple answer to how to encrypt files.
This script uses the [XOR encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) to encrypt files.
Encrypt the file a second time to decrypt it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void encrypt (string &key,string &data){
float percent;
for (int i = 0;i < data.size();i++){
percent = (100*i)/key.size();              //progress of encryption
data[i] = data.c_str()[i]^key[i%key.size()];
if (percent < 100){                        
    cout << percent << "%\r";              //outputs percent, \r makes
}else{                                     //cout to overwrite the
    cout<< "100%\r";                       //last line.
}
}

}
int main()
{
string data;
string key = "This_is_the_key";
ifstream in ("File",ios::binary); // this input stream opens the 
                                  // the file and ...
data.reserve (1000);
in >> data;                       // ... reads the data in it.
in.close();
encrypt(key,data);                
ofstream out("File",ios::binary);//opens the output stream and ...
out << data;                     //... writes encrypted data to file.
out.close();


return 0;
}
```

This line of code is where the encryption happens:

```
data[i] = data.c_str()[i]^key[i%key.size()];
```

it encrypts each byte individually.
Each byte is encrypted with a char that changes during the encryption
because of this:

```
key[i%key.size()]
```

But there are a lot of encryption methods, for example you could add 1 to each byte(encryption) and subtract 1 from each byte(decryption):

```
//Encryption
for (int i = 0;i < data.size();i++){
    data[i] = data.c_str()[i]+1;
}
//Decryption
for (int i = 0;i < data.size();i++){
    data[i] = data.c_str()[i]-1;
}
```

I think the it's not very useful to show the progress because it is to fast.

If you really want to make a GUI I would recommend Visual Studio.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: How would I show the progress on GUI while encryption and decryption ?

Comment: With a progress bar (Visual Studio provides an easy way).

Comment: Which IDE(Integrated development environment(Code::Blocks,Visual Studio, etc...)) are you using?

Comment: I use Code::Blocks for everything.

Comment: Try gtk to make a GuI

Comment: ... application, Code::Blocks -> File -> New -> Project -> gtk project.

Comment: If you get this error "cannot find gtk/gtk.h" then click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921460/how-to-setup-gtk-to-develop-with-codeblocks-on-ubuntu-linux).

Comment: sorry I got busy and didn't had time to check in here